# CSS: Setting a specific table cell height in percentage of the screen?

Tags: html, css

Say that I have a table with two rows, and a cell in each. I want the first cell to have a height of 70% of the screen or webbrowser window.

If the height property is set in tr or td the cell get height in percentage of the table not the screen. I don't want the whole table in percentage of the screen because I want the second cell to be able to expand down without limit if content is added to it. Is that possible?

/Tomas

Comment: Are you using tables for layout?

Comment: Yes, however after reading the answers I geuss I should use divs instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set body margins and paddings to 0 in your stylesheet file:

```
body {
   padding: 0;
   margin: 0
}
```

Set your table's width to 100%:

```
<table style="width: 100%">
```

Set yours cell's width to 70%:

```
<table style="width: 100%">
   <tr>
      <td style="width: 70%">
```

And now forget all the above excepting body margin and padding and use:

```
    <div style="width: 70%"></div>
    <div></div>
```

Comment: Yes, this gives me exactly what I want, except height instead of width :), thanks!

Answer (score 0):

When you set a height as 70%, **it will be 70% of the height of its parent element**, in this case the table.

So If you use tables out would be forced to **give the whole table a height of 100%** and then table cell should auto-expand by default.

is this what you mean?

Comment: But Jordan is right, you should avoid using tables for layout, divs and css are the standard.

Comment: I tried this and the auto expand is into the table. That is, the table is still 100% of screen and the second cell expands up so that the first cell takes up less than 70%. But as you say I should use divs and css instead. Thanks :)